# Remove form namespace in Symfony2 form (for REST API)

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I'm designing REST API with Symfony2.

For POST and PUT request i'm using a FormType. Something like :

```
class EmailType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('subject', 'textarea')
        [...]
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'email';
    }
}
```

But when I POST, i'm must pass fields with a namespace like :

```
{
    "email": {
        "subject": "subject"
    }
}
```

But I don't want this top-level namespace !

Any ideas ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I've used Symfony forms for JSON based APIs. You just need to change your `getName()` method to return `''`:

```
public function getName()
{
    return '';
}
```

This, cobined with the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle), made working with POSTed data very easy.

Answer (score 7):

A form type has to have a name because if you register it as a service tagged as a form type, you need to somehow reference it. In the following code snippet, `email` is the name of the form type:

```
$form = $this->formFactory->create('email', $email);
```

That's why you have to return a name in the form type class:

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'email';
}
```

So, instead of creating a *form type* without a name, just create a *form* — a particular instance of that *form type* — with an empty name:

```
$form = $this->formFactory->createNamed(null, 'email', $email);
```

An empty string — `''` — instead of `null` works as well.

Comment: I know you didn't like the approach I suggested above. Could you add some detail in your answer about how this is a better way of dealing with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @StuBez I think it is worth changing this to the answer, as it is the better solution to attack this problem.

Comment: @Dan I can't see any way to change the accepted answer but you could try contacting the person who asked the question.

Comment: Totally meant to call out to @Gilles